# How to make Rigidbody2D.Simulated to stay true after hitting Play in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am making Flappy Bird style game and Rigidbody2D.simulated sets ifself false after pressing Play to test the app. Where do I have to put the `rigidbody.simulated = true` to make sure it stays this way and I am able to switch it off later?

If I put it in void `Update()` then void `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)` will not work like it's supposed to.

```
Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

Quaternion downRotation;
Quaternion forwardRotation;

void Start()
{
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    //it doesn't work if I put it here

    downRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,-90);
    forwardRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 35);


}

void Update()
{

    //if I put it here then void OnTriggerEnter2D() will not work

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        transform.rotation = forwardRotation;
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * tapForce, ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, downRotation, tiltSmooth * Time.deltaTime);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "ScoreZone")
    {
        // ToDo: register a score event
        // Play a sound
    }

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "DeadZone")
    {
        rigidbody.simulated = false;
        //register a dead event
        //play a sound
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure its set properly in the Unity Inspector.

Comment: OnTriggerEnter2D wont work because Update method will make `rigidbody.simulated` true per every frame. you can set it false at `Start()` not `Update()`.

Comment: @TheBatman Here is the Unity Inspector before and after play:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5qlyxg9d3c99ot5/Screenshot%202019-04-30%2016.46.59.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbs20fx4800hyfz/Screenshot%202019-04-30%2016.47.57.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your current code. `rigidbody.simulated` only needs to be marked as true in the inspector.

The problem seems to be a overlapping collider that is triggering this code to as soon as it starts.

```
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "DeadZone")
    {
        rigidbody.simulated = false;
//put the debug here
    }
```

try putting a `Debug.log(collision.gameObject.name);` to find out which gameObject is causing that.

Comment: Here is the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bj83j6ua3z75c36/Screenshot%202019-05-01%2014.07.34.png?dl=0
Don't see how the top_pipe can affect rigidbody.simulated

Comment: I removed Box Collider 2D from both pipes and readded them one more time. It works now. Simple as that. Thank you for the Debug.Log suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Removed BoxCollider2D from objects that Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.name); called for and then added them again. Works like a charm now.